# SQL Server : copy database data and structure including aspnet security to blank database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-backups

I have to transfer the data and structure of a SQL Server database to an already created empty database.

I have 4 tables with auto-increment keys, where 3 tables are sub tables of the master. The database also has the ASP.NET membership tables, which I need to copy across as has user data.

Any ideas, I have tried usually SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, but won't keep the auto inc keys and ASP.NET membership tables.

Comment: you can take backup of DB and restore on empty DB. Follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx  and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx

Comment: It wont let me do it as its via a website panel, and i cannot use the same db name. maybe iam doing it wrong.?

Comment: Then make your question Clear, what and where you want? and let us know what you tried till now, what problem you getting

Comment: Ok. bit more info.  I have successfully created a backup of the database in question using sql management studio to my local drive folder. On the destination server i dont have the option to name the db as the same name. Due to the providers auto naming prefix which it attaches. When i try and restore the db to this newly created db, i use vs man studio, select the file location of the backup in the device option and choose the new database database in the destination folder. The verify backup media works ok but the restore fails.  I can restore it to its original name.  Any ideas

Comment: Ok. changed the filename and overite option and now working.

Answer (score 1):

You have two simple options

1. [`backup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187510.aspx) and [`Restore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177429.aspx) database on the target server.
2. But since you have mentioned you want to copy the data and schema from one database to another empty(existing) database, I would suggest [`SQL Server Scripting`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would be a better option for you. You can scripts sql-server objects and data (just data or just schema) and execute these scripts on the target database.